# Disabling AutoPostback on gridview asp:hyperlinkfield?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to execute some javascript on the click of a asp gridview's hyperlinkfield. The javascript executes fine but the page posts back so when the iframe flickers before showing (The javascript simply sets the iframe's source and then its display from none to block.). How can I go about disabling autopostback on this control since it does not have such an attribute?

```
<Columns>
<asp:hyperlinkfield Text="Update"
                    NavigateUrl="javascript:ShowForm('frmAddAudits.aspx');"
                    HeaderText="Update"
                    target="_blank"/>
<asp:hyperlinkfield Text="Add Findings"
                    NavigateUrl="javascript:ShowForm('frmAuditFindings.aspx');"
                    HeaderText="Add Findings"
                    target="_blank" />
</Columns>
```

CSS

```
.ShowMe{display:block;} 
.HideMe{display:none;}
```

Javascript

```
function ShowForm(urlToGoTo){
document.getElementById('myiFrame').src = urlToGoTo;
document.getElementById('myiFrame').className = "ShowMe";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the TemplateFiled and the anchor tag like this :

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>

             <a href="#" onclick="javascript:ShowForm('frmAddAudits.aspx');return false;">
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

if you want you can set `runat="server"` and give it an `ID`

Answer (score 1):

In your javascript event handler add `return false` so the browser does not continue the click action, in this case doing the postback.

Of course, ideally, you wouldn't be using `<asp:HyperlinkField>`. Have you considered using `<a runat="server">` instead?

Comment: I have tried that but then it does not execute any of the code in the javascript that occures before the return false?

Comment: Could it be that the page does not actually post back, but the iFrame flashed as it loads? How could I, in the ShowForm javascript function, check that the iFrame is loaded before setting its display style from none to block?

Comment: You never said anything about having an `<iframe>` in your page, nor have we seen the content of your `ShowForm` function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this NavigateUrl attribute in the markup

`NavigateUrl="javascript:ShowForm('frmAddAudits.aspx');return false;"`

And also you can try basic HTML anchor tag and javascript to open new window.

Comment: I have tried that but then it does not execute any of the code in the javascript that occures before the return false?

Comment: I have tried the anchor tag but the asp gridview does not allow the tag in the colums..

Comment: use ItemTemplate and add the anchor tag

Answer (score 1):

```
 NavigateUrl="javascript:ShowForm('frmAddAudits.aspx');return false"
```

Comment: then theres probably something that triggers the postback in your showform function...is it just for redirecting?

Comment: its not for redirecting at all. It sets the source of a hidden iframe on the page, and then show the iframe.

Answer (score 1):

See if you are not doing anything on postback of these hyper links then what is the purpose to draw server side control.

These affects the performance while rendering on web page. So I would suggest you to use `<a>` insread of these hyperlinkfields

you can use instead :

```
            <a href="#" onclick="javascript:ShowForm('frmAddAudits.aspx');return false;">
```

Postback will never occure in this case and reduce the rendering time and momory cost in comparative to byperlinkfield.